# Sails response - json object key not in alphabetical order

Tags: node.js, sails.js, postman

I am using Sails.js "one to many" model method mentioned here:-
https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/one-to-many

This is the postman response I got when fetching http://3.1.168.173:1337/articles/ with GET method.

```
[
    {
        "translations": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "title": "Voluptate quo animi minima est maiores assumenda.",
                "content": "Molestiae quidem quae consequatur fuga possimus nisi expedita quia.",
                "locale": "en-us",
                "article_id": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "title": "Pariatur asperiores quo quia voluptates nihil error porro.",
                "content": "Vel reprehenderit eos dolorum qui tempora rerum.",
                "locale": "zh-cn",
                "article_id": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "title": "Quibusdam unde iure et veniam cupiditate.",
                "content": "Rerum id ut odit reprehenderit eos sunt.",
                "locale": "zh-hk",
                "article_id": 2
            }
        ],
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Et nihil veritatis voluptatem molestiae modi nihil et aut.",
        "published_at": null
    }
]
```

I observe the object key "translations" is not in alphabetical order with other keys like id, name and published_at. I wish them to be in alphabetical order.

If I wish to make them in alphabetical order, is there any related sails model settings can achieve that? Or I need to use self written codes to do so?

Article.js

```
module.exports = {

  datastore: 'lightSail',

  tableName: 'articles',

  attributes: {

    name: {
      type: "string",
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    published_at: {
      type: "string",
      allowNull: true
    },
    translations: {
      collection: 'ArticleTranslation',
      via: 'article_id'
    }

  },

};
```

ArticleTranslation.js

```
module.exports = {

  datastore: 'lightSail',

  tableName: 'article_translations',

  attributes: {
    title: {
      type: "string",
      required: true
    },
    content: {
      type: "string",
      required: true
    },
    locale: {
      type: "string",
      required: true
    },
    article_id: {
      model: 'Article'
    }

  },

};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use sort in populate to sort populated array like that,

`.populate('foo', { sort: 'comments ASC' }).exec(...)`